# Are cognitive functions strictly divided in the left and right hemispheres?

Tags: neuroscience, neuroanatomy, brain

[image]

I often see this kind of picture, claiming the strict lateralization of brain functions. Is this valid?

Then, what happens to left-handed individuals? Are their cognitive functions also switched around?

Lastly, I thought that analytical skills reside mostly in the prefrontal cortex, irrespective whether it's left or right.

Comment: Related: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/6532 https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/16099 https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/6522

Comment: The question is indeed duplicate. What will happen to this question? Will it be deleted or will this be a stub where people finding this questions on search engine can find other questions?

Comment: @SharenEayrs - as of now, the question will be left in place such that it can lead people to the dupe questions. Quite frankly, after editing the post slightly, I like your post better than the linked one. In fact, I doubt whether it's a dupe, as you specifically ask about left and right handed people. So I'm still not too convinced :-) But if you say your answer is over there, it's all good.

Comment: One of the similar questions also talked about whether lefties think differently and the answer is no. Actually some that says it false actually corroborate the theory. Some answers, for example, say that the right brain decode the intonation and stresses in language while the left brain decode the actual words.